# Вычитываю с mysql,быстрее чем записываю

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, php7

С начало я обрабатываю запрос классом Handler()(связался через curl со своим сервером отдал данные, если мне не хватает информации, я подключаю js.

JS отправляет данные ко мне на сервер в базу данных.

После вызываю new HandlerAnswerJS php через curl прошу полную ифну которая сформировалась в mysql.

Но проблема в том, что я получаю в поле запроса null,а в базе я вижу полноценные значения.

Получается еще не обработало данные и не записала их, а я уже выполнил запрос.

КАк решить проблему, таймаут ставить не совсем хорошо.
Цикл $fieldmsyql != null тоже не решение.

```
      $res = false;
       if ($res = (new Handler())->runHandler()) {
          echo '<script src="/folder/handlerGeneral.js"></script>
         <script 
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js</script>
         <script src="/folder/handler.js"></script>';
       if ((new HandlerAnswerJS)->runHandler()) {
          $res = true;
  }  
} 




    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input")););
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 500);
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял, но видимо вы отправляете данные и не дожидаясь выполнения записи пытаетесь ихже получить, в таком случае в аякс запросе есть метод success, done, который дождется ответа а уже потом вы сможете выполнить новый запрос на получение, если речь идет о php, то там само собой пока не выполнится запись, не будет выполняться и следующий код на чтение, вы видимо перемудрили с логикой записи и получения данных, еще раз почитайте про то чем вы пользуетесь и перестройте логику выполнения своей задачи

Comment: Да ты прав, сделал ajax, дождался ответа и сделал нужные мне действия.